# pass json array to another view controller and display it in different label using segue

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to send json array to another view controller and display it in different labels in another view controller ??

```
var sendData = [String: AnyObject]()
sendData = datas
print("Send Data : \(sendData)")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "checkLoginViewController", sender: sendData)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? signUpViewController {
            if let sendmyArray = sender as? [String]{
                destinationVC.myarray = sendmyArray
            }
}
```

signUpViewController.swift:

```
var myarray = [String]()
var myemail = ""
var myname = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MynameLabel.text = myname
    nameTextfield.text = myemail
    myarray = [myemail,myname]
    print(myarray)        
    print(myemail)
    print(myname)
}
```

i am able to fetch the array but the i am not able to send the array to another view controller and the i have to display it in different label

Comment: you are overriding it straight away `myarray = [myemail,myname]`

Comment: so how i can display it in both textfields "MynameLabel" and "nameTextfield" is my method is wrong ?? @Scriptable

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. should the array contain the JSON data or the values from the two textfields?

Comment: ok if i want to pass two data to next view controller ? and after passing it to next view controller i want to display it on different label how i can do that

Comment: array contains two data [name:sandesh, email:sandesh@gmail.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up array and dictionary

- `sendData` is dictionary (`[String: AnyObject]`)
- `myarray` is array (`[String]`)

Of course optional downcast `sender as? [String]` fails because the sender is a dictionary.

As the source is a dictionary with `String` keys and values change the code to

```
var sendData = [String: String]()

...

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
   if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? signUpViewController,
      let sendmyDictionary = sender as? [String: String] { 
         destinationVC.myDictionary = sendmyDictionary
   }
}
```

And in the second controller

```
var myDictionary = [String: String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    MynameLabel.text = myDictionary["name"]
    nameTextfield.text = myDictionary["email"]
}
```

---

Note : An unspecified value type dictionary in Swift 3+ is `[String:Any]` and according to the naming convention variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: but i want to pass two data to another view controller and in next view controller i want to display it in textfield for eg:FirstVC : name: sandesh email: sandesh@gmail.com these are the data i am getting through json now i want to send these data and want to display it in textfields

Comment: sorry for replying late ... it worker thank so very much @vadian